# Sub-Class common List methods into a Serializable Class

Tags: c#, oop, serialization

I am trying to consolidate some common functionality.

I have several `serializable` classes that hold a List of a `serializable` objects of a unique type.

For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class ArrowData {

public List<ArrowItem> listOfItems;

public ArrowData() {
    listOfItems = new List<ArrowItem>();

}
//ADD
public void AddItemToInventory(ArrowItem item) {
    listOfItems.Add(item);
}

//DELETE
public void RemoveItemFromInventory(ArrowItem item) {
    listOfItems.Remove(item);
}

//CLEAR ALL
public void RemoveAllInventory() {
    listOfItems.Clear();
}

//GET ALL
public List<ArrowItem> GetFullListOfInventory() {
    return listOfItems;
}

//Unique methods for ArrowData down here

}


[Serializable]
public class SwordData {

public List<SwordItem> listOfItems;

public ArrowData() {
    listOfItems = new List<SwordItem>();

}
//ADD
public void AddItemToInventory(SwordItem item) {
    listOfItems.Add(item);
}

//DELETE
public void RemoveItemFromInventory(SwordItem item) {
    listOfItems.Remove(item);
}

//CLEAR ALL
public void RemoveAllInventory() {
    listOfItems.Clear();
}

//GET ALL
public List<SwordItem> GetFullListOfInventory() {
    return listOfItems;
}

//Unique methods for SwordData down here

}
```

I'd like to put all the "CRUD" operations into their own class and just have my ArrowData, SwordData, etc.. inherit from it.

So I started this:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class DataProcessor<T> where T : List<T> {

    public List<T> listOfItems;

    public DataProcessor(T type) {

        listOfItems = new List<type>();


    }
    //ADD
    public void AddItemToInventory(T item) {
        listOfItems.Add(item);
    }

    //DELETE
    public void RemoveItemFromInventory(T item) {
        listOfItems.Remove(item);
    }

    //CLEAR ALL
    public void RemoveAllInventory() {
        listOfItems.Clear();
    }

    //GET ALL
    public List<T> GetFullListOfInventory() {
        return listOfItems;
    }
}
```

So that my `ArrowData` class would look something in the realm of this:
This is just psuedocode since I don't yet know how to implement this.

```
[Serializable]
public class ArrowData  : DataProcessor {

    public ArrowData() {
        listOfItems = new DataProcessor(ArrowItem);

    }
}
```

Where I am passing in the unique object I want a list of.

But I don't know enough about what I want to accomplish to Google it or if such a process is possible.

Any help?

Comment: You want public class ArrowData : DataProcessor<ArrowItem>

Also, just name your methods add and remove, and implement Ilist. That way, you could utilize a whole bunch of existing extension methods

Comment: Thank you for the advice @realbart . What is this pattern called? So I can better read up on it?

Comment: @user-44651 It's a "generic repository" pattern.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys this worked really well!